# Magento: Order has invoice (generated) but 'Total due' > 0

Tags: php, magento, invoice

I have a live Magento 1.5.0.1 webshop, with the following problem:

We have received an order, which has been paid for through iDEAL (Dutch online payment service) and an invoice has been auto-generated on payment success. We have also received the amount on our bank account.

The only thing is, we cannot complete the order because of the 'Total due' field being an amount higher than 0 (zero). This must be a bug in our iDEAL-module (which will be dealt with at another moment).

Is there a way to 'force' this particular order to be 'complete' with the Total due field set to 0?

Obviously, PHP-code examples to do so are quite welcome (I am a programmer myself).

Comment: How big is this total due? Is this the same as original? Or might be 0.01?

Comment: It's the same as Grand total (so larger than 0.01) and by the way Total paid is 0.00 (which is not true, because the order has been paid for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you.

Example from one of our modules:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
if ($order->getTotalPaid() == 0) {
    $invoice = $order->prepareInvoice();
    $invoice->register()->capture();
    Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
        ->addObject($invoice)
        ->addObject($invoice->getOrder())
        ->save();
    $order->save();
```

This checks if payment was not yet registered(user might send several successful requests by multi clicking) then creates invoice, registers it, captures and save invoice and orders.

**EDIT 1**

```
private function markOrderPayd($incrementId, $status) {
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
        if ($order->getTotalPaid() == 0) {
            ... 
            $order->save();
            $invoice = $order->prepareInvoice();
            $invoice->register()->capture();
            ...
            Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                ->addObject($invoice)
                ->addObject($invoice->getOrder())
                ->save();
            $order->save();
            ...

        } else {
            ...
            $order->save();
        }
}
```

I guess you don't have any check, so 2 invoices are generated.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! The order is complete and 'Total due'=0 and Total paid == Grand total. The only thing is, that I have two invoices with one order, but I can live with that ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I do not fully understand. You use the resource_transaction to complete the order and by that you have to create an invoice. There was already an invoice but somehow this was not captured right. Is there a way to not create an extra invoice and mark this order complete?

Comment: Check for the if ($order->getTotalPaid() == 0) {. So if it paid, then invoice not need to be generated.

Comment: I'm not getting where to change? can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Thanks! In my case the left out is the COD fee. Before I proceed to run this code, could you explain witch item will be add to the invoice? I think the second invoice should have in totals the COD fee with Subtotal 0, right?

Comment: Edit: I've proceeded to create the second invoice, that was created without items but subtotal is not equal to 0! Screenshot: http://imgur.com/PCbKEya

Comment: @andreacanton, basically you could check for another  value, not subtotal.