# Magento: Payments not automatically set "total due"-->"total paid" after 1.8.1.0 update

Tags: magento

I have run my Magento 1.7.0.2 store with an external payment service (and their module installed) without any trouble for a year, but after updating to Magento 1.8.1.0 I got a little problem with the payments, exactly as this question: [Magento: Order has invoice (generated) but 'Total due' > 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721345/magento-order-has-invoice-generated-but-total-due-0) . Problem is that I am not a programmer (just understand some basics), plus I haven't gotten much help from the module supplier (they just claim that "it *should* work on 1.8.x.x). Payments via PayPal and bank transfer work and set the payment state normally.

In detail, the payments made via this external payment service are not setting the "total due" to "total paid" anymore, which causes the order statuses to stay in the state "processing". Furthermore, since the payment is not correctly handled, the Magento dashboard statistics are not updating anymore. It still does the rest of the flow normally: redirects the customer to the payment service and back normally -> creates an invoice with state "paid", but only leaves the order "total due".

I can force the order status to "complete" manually, but any advice with two questions would be much appreciated:

- Is there a way to manually set the payment status afterwards from "total due" to "total paid"? Now I have quite a few orders that are not updated, thus the statistics are completely wrong.
- I assume that the problem is in the payment module rather than a broken update of Magento, since everything else works fine. However I'm a bit at loss with what has changed in Magento, that could cause the above mentioned problem